# How to get rid of words in a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a beginner in python and programming in general.
I'm trying to get rid of certain words in a text file. I have a .txt file with the words I'm trying to get rid of in the first text file.
My code looks like this now, but it's not working the way it's supposed to:

```
commonWords = "common.txt"
commonFile = open(commonWords, "r").read()

for cw in "commonWords":
    text = text.replace(cw, " ")
```

Any ideas to make this work?

Comment: You need to write the changes to your file again in order to preserve them. `text = text.replace(cw, " ")` os changing the text only in the scope of this script and changes won't be reflected in the file unless you save it again.

Comment: Which are these "certain words"? Btw you are iterating in every character of the string `commonWords` I don't know if this is the behaviour you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to extract words from your file:

```
filepath = "common.txt"
words_file_content = open(filepath, "r").read()

words = set(words_file_content.split())  # get separate words from file

for word in words:
    text = text.replace(word, "")
```